# point directory folder using php

Tags: php

I am trying to point to my directory, but not sure how I do it?

My script is like this:

```
if(is_dir('./anotherfolder/'.$schedule['folder'])) {
            $schedules[$key]['files'] = array();
            $files = scandir('./anotherfolder/'.$schedule['folder']);
```

And this index file is in this directory `folder/index.php`.
I want to point it to `anotherfolder/page1.php`.

That means I have to exit **folder** and go back then enter **another-folder**

Comment: You can use the `..` parent folder selector in PHP.

Comment: like this i get bunch of errors `is_dir('../anotherfolder/'.$schedule['folder']`

Comment: That is the proper way, please add the errors you get to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__DIR__` instead of `..` like so:

```
if (is_dir(__DIR__.'/anotherfolder/') {
```

When you are in `folder/index.php`.

Or you could use `file_exists` to check if php file is in that folder:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/anotherfolder/page1.php') {
```

Comment: like this did not work `$files = scandir(__DIR__.'./anotherfolder/'.$schedule['folder']`

Comment: Don't add a dot before your folder in path, just use `/antoherfolder/`